If $a,b,c$ are positive real numbers, find the minimum of $E = a^4 + 2b^4 + 4c^4 - 8abc$ and the corresponding values of $a,b,c$.
I tried using AM-GM inequality
$$(a^4+2b^4+4c^4)/3 \geq 2(abc)^{4/3}.$$
I also  tried
$$[a^4 + b^4 + b^4 + c^4 + c^4 + c^4 + c^4]/7 \geq (a^4b^8c^{16})^{1/7}.$$
But I couldn't get the minimum value of $E$, also I couldn't find the value of $a,b,c$ at which the minimum occurs.

Welcome to math SE. Have a look at mathjax for your mathematical expressions.

According to the AM-GM inequality,
$$
a^4+2b^4+4c^4\geq 6(abc)^{4/3}, \tag{1}
$$
hence
$$
E\geq 6(abc)^{4/3}-8abc. \tag{2}
$$
Let $abc=x$; then, to obtain the minimum of $E$ we must solve $f'(x)=0$, where $f(x)=6x^{4/3}-8x$:
$$
f'(x)=0 \implies 8x^{1/3}-8=0 \implies x=1, \tag{3}
$$
which implies
$$
E\geq 6-8 = -2, \tag{4}
$$
so the minimum value of $E$ is $-2$.
To find the values of $a,b,c$ that minimize $E$, we notice that $(1)$ is an equality when $a^4=2b^4=4c^4$, hence
$$
abc=1 \implies a^4\cdot 2b^4\cdot 4c^4 = 8 \implies (a^4)^3=8 \implies a=2^{1/4}, \tag{5.1}
$$
$$
b^4=\frac{a^4}{2}=\frac{2}{2}=1 \implies b=1, \tag{5.2} 
$$
$$
c^4=\frac{a^4}{4}=\frac{2}{4}=\frac{1}{2} \implies c=2^{-1/4}. \tag{5.3}
$$

I was thinking of this method too +1
